# PostgreSQL: How to UPSERT table using another table based on two primary keys?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has two primary keys, `first_name` and `last_name` and also has about 10 other columns. I want to update it using another table that has the exact same schema but many have new values to add or update to the old table. What is the correct SQL query?

[image: Here is a picture of what I am trying to do]

The code I have so far is:

```
UPDATE OLD_DATA AS old
SET val_1 = new.val_1 ,
    val_2 = new.val_2 ,
FROM NEW_DATA AS new
WHERE old.first_name = new.first_name
AND   old.last_name  = new.last_name
```

But this doesn't add new data, it only updates old data.

Comment: You don't want to specify columns to update?

Comment: No, I want it to update all the columns.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html) is the documentation on postgres updates.

```
update old_data set val_1 = 5 and val_2 = 1
where first_name = 'donald' and last_name = 'duck'
```

Do the same for each row.